# Nested queryset update

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Due to some file uploading features I have denormalized db. Users could post one EventComment per Event and few Images. Images were stored separately from comments. Now I need to connect them and set a task that will do this once per day.

```
class EventComment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('user')
    event = models.ForeignKey('event')

class Image(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('user')
    event = models.ForeignKey('event')
    foo = models.ForeignKey('foo', null=True, blank=True)
```

I very much don't want to do this that way:

```
for i in Image.objects.filter(eventcomment__isnull=True):
    i.eventcomment = EventComment.objects.get(event=i.event, author=i.author)
    i.save()
```

What is a correct way to write nested queryset? I tried this way, but I get DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "event"

```
Image.objects.filter(eventcomment__isnull=True).update(eventcomment=EventComment.objects.get(event=Value('event'), author=Value('author')))
```

EDIT:

For this case I should wrap queryset in try/catch clause:

```
for i in Image.objects.filter(eventcomment__isnull=True):
    try:
        i.eventcomment = EventComment.objects.get(event=i.event, author=i.author)
        i.save()
    exception (EventComment.DoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned):
        i.delete()
```

But if I wanted to write it in one line, which in my case would return MultipleObjectReturned exception could write it with F expression:

```
Image.objects.filter(eventcomment__isnull=True).update(eventcomment=EventComment.objects.get(event=F('event__id'), author=F('author__id')
```

Comment: What's going on if EventComment.objects.get() don't return something ? You need to catch exception.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get

Comment: In my case it never happens. Moreover error message is about integer "event", which should be id, isn't it?

Comment: Can you display the error message. It's may be a event object. Not the id.

Comment: DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "event__id"
LINE 1: ...ents_eventcomment" WHERE ("events_eventcomment"."event_id" = ('event__id...

Comment: ReportPhoto.objects.filter(report__isnull=True).update(report=Report.objects.get(event=F('event__id'), author=F('author__id'))) it looks better, but raises MultipleObjectsReturned. Maybe that solves the question

Comment: MultipleObjectsReturned is an error raise by Get(). See my previous url.
You are using Value('event') of you Image filter. But filter can return MultipleObjects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132107/discussion-between-wilfried-and-piotr-peczek).